# When does Tomcat unpack a war file to a ROOT folder?

Tags: java, tomcat, war, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a war on Tomcat 7.0, and in the `server.xml` file, I've set `unpackWARs = true` and `autoDeploy = true`.

Since I want this war file to be the default web application, I have deleted the ROOT folder inside `...Tomcat7.0/webapps`. Then on, when I try to start the Tomcat service, I see a behavior that I have yet failed to identify a pattern in:

- Sometimes, the war is unpacked to a newly created folder named
  'ROOT'.
- Some other times, it is unpacked to a folder that is named
  the same as the name of the war file. E.g. if the war file is
  'MyWebApp.war', it's unpacked to a folder named 'MyWebApp'.

It seems to be completely erratic and random, but I am sure there is method behind this apparent madness. As a rule, I am not sure if there is anything that dictates the creation of a ROOT folder. I have tried to edit the server.xml file and add context to my web application in it, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Name your war file ROOT.war. It will unpack to ../webapps/ROOT and map to / context

Comment: On simply changing the name to root.war with the context set and nothing else, Tomcat crashes with the following errors:

Feb 06, 2014 3:57:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()

Feb 06, 2014 3:57:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured

Feb 06, 2014 3:57:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 06, 2014 3:57:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR

Comment: Also, even if I get the webapp running, I am curious from an academic standpoint: why would unpacking a war be to differently named folders when nothing has been mentioned in any configuration file? What prompts the creation of a ROOT folder in particular?

Comment: Because it does. Have a look at the manual http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me toward the link. The answer to my question is in the Naming section under Introduction in the page. I have looked at this page in the past, but obviously missed it. Marking and resolving as answer.